# search and load results jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

I'm fairly new to AJAX / jQuery, I'm just exploring things
this is my problem I have a textbox and what I want to do is if I click the search button, search results will load on (#sort-results) I don't know what's wrong with this.. I hope anyone could make me understand even more. Thanks.

**Index.php**

```
<input type="text" name="item_type" class="item_type"></td>
        <select class="location">
          <option value="bldg1">bldg1</option>
          <option value="bldg2">bldg2</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn_search">Search</button>

      <div id="sort-results"></div>
```

**Script.js**

```
$(".btn_search").click(function(){
  type = $(".item_type").val();
  location = $(".location").val();
    if(type.length > 0){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "sort.php",
      data: "type="+type +"location="+location,
      cache:false,
      success : function(){
        $("#sort-results").html();
      }

    });
   }
```

});

**Sort.php**

```
require 'global/db.php';
require_once 'config.php';
$type = $_GET['type'];
$location = $_GET['location'];

$db = new Database(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DB);
$selection = $db->select("SELECT * FROM os_inventory WHERE os_type like '$type' AND os_location like '$location'");
echo "<table class=bordered>
        <tr><th>Item</th>
        <th>Item Code</th>
        <th>Item Type</th>
        <th>Serial No.</th>
        <th>Date Added</th>
        </tr>";
foreach ($selection as $key) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $key['os_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $key['os_type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $key['os_code'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $key['os_serial'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $key['os_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you forgetting to actually pass the content through?

```
success : function(html){
             $("#sort-results").html(html);
          }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The code I posted above is a correction of your `jQuery.ajax` code in the original question. The `jQuery.ajax` method takes an object of parameters, one of which can be the `success` callback. This callback takes parameters as defined in the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ The first parameter is the content of the response (I've given that parameter the name `html` in my fix above. The contents `html` of html then need to be put into the DOM, which you do with the `.html()` call.

Comment: Yup, my question is, what is wrong with my jquery/ajax code, because what I want to do is load the sort.php file on the same page without refresh using ajax/jquery. It only say Object not Found!

Comment: Where does it say "Object not Found"? Console? Alert? In the page content somewhere? All I did was correct your JavaScript. I don't know whether your PHP does what it should.

Comment: After I click the search button the page says Object not Found!

Comment: We don't have access to your database or PHP environment, so you're going to have to be more specific about where exactly it says that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I haven't seen jQuery selector use the period.  Change your selectors to:

```
$("#btn_search").click(function(){
      type = $("#item_type").val();
      location = $("#location").val();
```

Then do as per @David's post to actually receive code from the server to place in your DIV

Comment: The 'period' is the way you specify all elements with that specific CSS "class", rather than the single element with that specific `id` DOM attribute.